# Calculating standard errors for long-run (cumulative) multiplier in a Distributed Lag model

Tags: panel-data, standard-error, lags, dynamic-regression

I have a distributed lag model of the form:

```
lm(wellbeing ~ temperature + temperature_lag1 + temperature_lag2 + time + individual, df)
```

where I'm interested in finding out the long-run multiplier for the effect of daily temperatures on an individual's wellbeing.

I understand that the coefficient for the multiplier would simply be the sum of the beta coefficients for temperature, temperature_lag1 and temperature_lag2.

However, I'm not entirely sure how to go about calculating the standard error for the multiplier.

I've seen [suggestions](http://rizaudinsahlan.blogspot.com/2018/04/long-run-multiplier-estimation-with.html) for doing so by regressing:

```
dif1 <- temperature_lag1 - temperature
dif2 <- temperature_lag2 - temperature
lm(wellbeing ~ temperature + dif1 + dif2 + time + individual, df)
```

With the beta for temperature acting as the SE for the long-run multiplier. However, I'm not sure how valid this approach is?

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'd look into the [`dlnm`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=dlnm) package that explicitly fits distributed lag models.

Comment: Thanks. I'll certainly take a look at dlnm. Though at this stage, I'd be especially keen to understand the theory/practice behind how the SEs are calculated.